# Capturing repeated groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string `1xxx5xx1x7xxx8`. I want to get matches so that I have the following results:

```
match[0] = '1xxx5'
match[1] = '5xx1'
match[2] = '1x7'
match[3] =  '7xxx8'
```

So the basic pattern is get groups that have `1` or `more` `x` between digits. I have this basic regex so far but it doesn't work:

```
/\dx{1,}\d/
```

The string that I have used is just an example, the patterns could continue on for as long as what the string is.

Comment: I don't know of a regex engine where a found match can overlap with a next one. It's kind of basically not how matching works.

Comment: so, you want the 5, 1 and 7 to be matched twice - don't think you can do that

Comment: So instead of a single regex, look for some pretty basic looping code.

Comment: Ye, I want overlapping. I was suspecting that regex won't be able to do it but I'm not an expert so wanted to see if any regex magicians could confirm my suspicion

Comment: Yeah, this isn't really for regex. Try looking into the `indexOf()` method.

Comment: `'1xxx5xx1x7xxx8'.match(/(\dx*)/g).map((i, n, a) => n < a.length - 1 ? i + a[n+1][0] : null).filter(x => x)` gets what you want, but relies on the "validity" of the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to find matches one at a time and decrement [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) in between to start searching for next match with one character of overlap:

```js
var str = '1xxx5xx1x7xxx8';
var regex = /\dx+\d/g;

var matches = [], match;
while ( match = regex.exec( str ) ) {
  matches.push( match[ 0 ] );
  regex.lastIndex--; // Start next search one char back (overlap matches)
}

console.log( matches );
```

Comment: Never knew about `lastIndex`, this is awesome

Answer (score 1):

Regex engines don't support overlapping matches, but you can use the trick in Paulpro's answer. Or you can write your own algorithm for this:

```
var myString = "1xxx5xx1x7xxx8";
var matches = [];
var curMatch = "";
for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; ++i) {
  var char = myString[i];
  if (char === "x") { // assumes you only have numbers or x's
    curMatch += char;
    continue;
  }

  if (curMatch) {
      matches.push(curMatch + char);
  }

  curMatch = char;
}

console.log(matches)
```